# Incorrect k8s deployment file

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

I am following Cloud Guru K8S course and have issues with the template they provided. I can't see what’s wrong.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: blue-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: bluegreen-test
      color: blue
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: bluegreen-test
        color: blue
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: linuxacademycontent/ckad-nginx:blue
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

When I run

```
kubectl apply -f my-deployment.yml
```

I get

```
error: error parsing blue-deployment.yml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 4: found character that cannot start any token
```

What's wrong with this template? It's nearly identical to the official example deployment definition https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Comment: 1st do `cat -A <deployment.yml>` then do a `dos2unix <deployment.yml>` then retry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template is correct, it's just YAML that's complaining. YAML doesn't accept tabs, only 2 spaces. If you copied + pasted, it could have caused a discrepancy. If you want to stay on terminal, `vim my-deployment.yml` and make sure each "tab" is 2 spaces. This is quite time-consuming especially in vim so the alternative is to use a text editor like Sublime Text to update it.

Comment: I used vim to edit the file so not sure why I have this issue. Perhaps it's the tabs that yaml doesn't like. I'll give it a try again but this time I'll replace tabs with spaces.

Comment: Yea, YAML only takes 2 spaces rather than tabs (use 2 spaces in vim as well). You can set up your favorite editor to associate a tab with 2 spaces so it helps with your dev work. Hope this helps to get your code working!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the yaml syntax. I just deployed it and it works. see below screenshot. Suggest you to use vi editor and add the manifest and then try. It should work

[image]

You can validate the syntax at the below link as well

https://validkube.com/